# _Static_assert in unused generic selection

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

It looks like the `typeof` operator is likely to be accepted into the next C standard, and I was looking to see if there was a way to leverage this to create a macro using portable ISO-C that can get the length of an array passed into it or fail to compile if a pointer is passed into it.  Normally generic selection can be used to force a compiler error when using an unwanted type by leaving it out of the generic association list, but in this case, we need a default association to deal with arrays of any length, so instead I am trying to force a compiler error for the generic association for the type we don't want.  Here's an example of what the macro could look like:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) _Generic(&(X), \
        typeof(&X[0]) *: sizeof(struct{_Static_assert(0, "Trying to get the array length of a pointer"); int _a;}), \
        default: (sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0])) \
)
```

The problem is that `_Static_assert` is tripping even when the generic association selected is the default association.  For sake of simplicity, since the issue at hand is not related anything being introduced in C23, we'll make a test program that works explicitly to reject a pointer to int:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) _Generic(&(X), \
        int **: sizeof(struct{_Static_assert(0, "Trying to get the array length of a pointer"); int _a;}), \
        default: (sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0])) \
)

int main(void) {

    int x[100] = {0};
    int *y = x;
    int (*z)[100] = {&x};

    printf("length of x: %zu\n", ARRAY_SIZE(x));
    printf("length of y: %zu\n", ARRAY_SIZE(y));
    printf("length of z: %zu\n", ARRAY_SIZE(z));
    printf("length of *z: %zu\n", ARRAY_SIZE(*z));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Building the above with `-std=c11`, I find `_Static_assert` tripping on all expansions of `ARRAY_SIZE` when I would expect to only have problems with the pointers that will use the `int **` generic association.

According to 6.5.1.1 p3 of the C11 standard for Generic Selection,

> None of the expressions from any other generic association of the generic selection is evaluated

Is this a bug in gcc and clang, or is there something I've missed in the standard that would cause the compile-time evaluation of this `_Static_assert` in the unused generic association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really mix `_Static_assert` with expressions that should return a value, such as a function-like macro. You could perhaps work around that with a "poor man's static assert", like one of the ugly tricks we used before C11:

```
#define POOR_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) (int[expr]){0}

#define CHECK(X) _Generic((&X), \
        int **: 0,\
        default: (sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0])) \
)

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) ( (void)POOR_STATIC_ASSERT(CHECK(X)), CHECK(X) )
```

Here the comma operator is called to have the macro `CHECK` return the size or zero, in case a type is valid or not. Then call the same macro again to have that one returned from the function-like macro `ARRAY_SIZE`. This will lead to some cryptic error from an ISO C compiler such as "error: ISO C forbids zero-size array".

---

The next problem is that `&(X)` in `_Generic` is by no means guaranteed to boil down to a `int**` so this macro isn't safe or reliable. Regarding array sizes though, there's a trick we can use. A pointer to an array of no size (incomplete type) is compatible with every array of the same element type no matter it's size. The macro could be rewritten as:

```
#define POOR_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) (int[expr]){0}

#define CHECK(X) _Generic((&X),              \
        int (*)[]: sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0]), \
        default: 0)

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) ( (void)POOR_STATIC_ASSERT(CHECK(X)), CHECK(X) )
```

This will work for any `int` array no matter size but fail for everything else.

Comment: I do like this approach.  I had tried finding other ways of forcing compiler errors, but all of them involved putting the error into one of the Generic selections rather than trying to use the value from the selection to force an error.  A couple of follow-up questions to this answer:  Is there any reason not to use a negative value rather than `0`?  The compiler I was testing with (clang 5) allowed zero-length arrays through an extension even when compiling with the iso c11 standard.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I guess you could as well use negative values. Or just compile with `-std=c17 -pedantic-errors` to disable gcc extensions.

Comment: Second follow-up:  Can you expand more on the last segment about it not being guaranteed to boil down to `int **`?  In this example, I was trying to simplify the problem to only dealing with `int`, but the end goal is to use the C23 _Typeof (or whatever notation it winds up using).  The fact that an array without a size can be used makes it a bit moot, but I'm still curious about the scenario in which the `int **` case doesn't work (or more-over, the `typeof(&X[0]) *`)

Comment: I also just tried replacing the contents of your `POOR_STATIC_ASSERT` with my `(sizeof(struct{ _Static_assert(expr, "Assert message"); int _a;}))`, and that actually worked.  So it seems that the key was to move the assert outside of the generic selection, and now a proper compiler error message can be created.

Comment: After some further testing, I've discovered a problem.  With my version that replaces your `POOR_STATIC_ASSERT` and uses a `_Static_assert`, the _Static_assert fails on use with Variable Length Array because the expression is not known at compile time.  With your original version, it fails with VLA because `sizeof` for a VLA is evaluated at run time, thus the array being created is a VLA which cannot be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which generic selection is evaluated.

When the expression that is part of a `_Status_assert` has the value 0, this is considered a constraint violation and the compiler is required to generate a diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing some of the suggestions from Lundin's answer, I have come up with the following solution to the simplified problem:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT_EXPRESSION(X, ERROR_MESSAGE) (sizeof(struct {_Static_assert((X), ERROR_MESSAGE); int _a;}))

#define NO_POINTERS(X) _Generic(&(X), \
    int (*)[]: 1, \
    default: 0 \
)

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) ( (void)STATIC_ASSERT_EXPRESSION(NO_POINTERS(X), "Cannot retrieve the number of array elements from a pointer"), (sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0])) )
```

For the actual use-case to be type generic using typeof, which should be coming to the C23 standard, replace the `NO_POINTERS` macro using this:

```
#define NO_POINTERS(X) _Generic(&(X), \
    typeof(*X) (*)[]: 1, \
    default: 0 \
)
```

By moving the `_Static_assert` outside of the Generic Selection, it will only be evaluated with the value that actually returns from the selection, so it won't get fired off for existing in an unused selection.  Additionally, the number of elements calculation was also removed from the generic selection so that expression of the generic selection could safely be used in a Static Assert even if your array was a Variable-Length array which requires its size to be calculated at run-time.

The Static Assert itself is placed inside of an anonymous struct that we take the sizeof so that it is a part of an expression.  And then as in Lundin's example, we use the comma operator to have that expression evaluated, and then thrown out and use the results of the array size calculation.

With this, we reject pointers while getting the number of elements in both static arrays and VLAs, plus we get a nice compiler error message when trying to pass in a pointer.